# Read file from different positions and put in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to read a file which looks like this:

```
Name=José, Age=21  
Name=Antonio, Age=26  
Name=Maria, Age=24
```

My problem is how can i read the names and ages from different positions and different lines and put in an array `names[size]` and the same thing for the ages       `ages[size]`.

I have this at the moment:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 100

int main()
{
    char ch = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char names[size];
    char ages[size];

    FILE *fp1;

    fp1 = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        return 1;
    }
    while((ch=fgetc(fp1)) != '=');
        while((ch=fgetc(fp1)) != ',')
        {
            fscanf(fp1, "%s", names);
            i++;
        }

    fclose(fp1);

    printf("Names = %s", names);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain me what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Use a `struct` for the data of each line, not two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need 2D-Array. E.g `names[number of record][max length size + 1]`
a way sample like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 100

int main(void){
    int i = 0;
    char names[size][128];
    char ages[size][4];

    FILE *fp1;

    fp1 = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(fp1 == NULL){
        printf("Error!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(i < size && 2 == fscanf(fp1, "Name=%127[^,], Age=%3[0-9]\n", names[i], ages[i])){
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp1);

    int n = i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("Names = %s, Ages = %s\n", names[i], ages[i]);

    return 0;
}
```